# Segmentation Fault with `std::pair<int, int>` C++

Tags: arrays, c++11, c++14, stdvector, std-pair

I am using a `std::vector` of `std::pair<int, int>`.

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > vec(n);
```

Where, `n` is the size of the `std::vector`.

I am taking input from `stdin` in this manner:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) std::cin>>vec[i].first>>vec[i].second;
```

Doing this, I get a segmentation fault. However, if I change my code to this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    int x, y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    vec[i] = std::make_pair(x, y);
}
```

It works just fine. I am unable to figure out what's wrong with the first one, since it is working in my PC on small inputs, but giving a SIGSEGV on large random input. Also, I get the same behavior on replacing the `vector` with a static `array` of `pair`.

Also, I have faced errors while using a `for` loop on a `vector` of `pair`. If I do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    std::cout<<vec[i].first<<" "<<vec[i].second<<"\n"
}
```

However, if I change it to:

```
for(auto x: vec){
    std::cout<<x.first<<" "<<x.second<<"\n"
}
```

It works just fine. What and where is the problem here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You say that "`n` is the size of the `std::vector`". Are you sure? Have you initialized it as a vector of size `n`? Or have you `resize()` it to `n`? I ask this because using a vector of zero size in this way give this type of errors.

Comment: I have initialized it with size `n`, with the same statement as mentioned.